# how to separate html list to 4 parts?

Tags: html

hello everyone i am creating a list type

which is  something like this

```
               <ul>
                    <li>Delhi</li>
                    <li>Mumbai</li>
                    <li>banglore</li>
                    <li>Gurgaon</li>
                    <li>Nainital</li>
                    <li>Lucknow</li>
                    <li>noida</li>
                    <li>Jaipur</li>
                    <li>Chnadigarh</li>
                    <li>Manli</li>
                    <li>Haryana</li>
                    <li>Goa</li>
                </ul>
```

but i want formatting like this

```
  Delhi           Gurgaon        noida         Manli    
  Mumbai          Nainital       Jaipur        Haryana
  banglore        Lucknow        Chnadigarh    Goa
```

Please help me to create this .
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following CSS

```
   ul {
    -webkit-column-count: 4; /*2 is just a placeholder -- can be anything*/
    -moz-column-count: 4;
    column-count:4;
    width: 100%; /*your fixed width*/
    height: 100%; /*your fixed height*/
  }
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nrsantharam/x2qaos6p/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS columns:

```
ul {
    -webkit-column-count: 4;
}
```

Note the browser prefix.

Comment: Ummm, if two people give the same answer, in this case to use CSS columns, then the earlier should be the accepted one.

Comment: @torazabura Agree but it would be nice if there would be fiddle demo in this answer. Anyways +1 from my side.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code if you want to use the HTML. Use below css in  tag

```
<style>
.table
{
width: 100%;
}
.tdclass
{
width: 80px;
}
</style>
```

And add the HTMl for this in the  tag

```
<table>
<tr>
<td class="tdclass">Delhi</td>
<td class="tdclass">Mumbai</td>
<td class="tdclass">Banglore</td>
<td class="tdclass">Gurgaon</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tdclass">Nainital</td>
<td class="tdclass">Lucknow</td>
<td class="tdclass">noida</td>
<td class="tdclass">Jaipur</td>
</tr>  
<tr>
<td class="tdclass">Chnadigarh</td>
<td class="tdclass">Manali</td>
<td class="tdclass">Haryana</td>
<td class="tdclass">Goa</td>
</tr> 
</table>
```

And with the List tag you can use the

```
ul {
-webkit-column-count: 4;
-moz-column-count: 4;
}
```